# How to retrieve mysql data based on timestamp for last 5 minutes using Java

Tags: mysql, api, jdbc

I am unable to get any result when I retrieved data from jdbc. In Database i am storing the timestamp of the server. How to retrieve the data for Last 5 minutes Below is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
        String user = "root";
        String password = "demo@123";
        String qry = "SELECT * FROM test.database WHERE EndTime >= date_sub(now(), interval 5 minute)";

        Connection conn = null;

        try 
        {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            ResultSet rs = conn.prepareStatement(qry).executeQuery();

            while(rs.next())
            {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("EventName"));
                System.out.println(rs.getTimestamp("EndTime"));
                System.out.println("-------------------");
            }
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when I run the Program, there is no result displayed in the console.
This is the Database data [image: Database Image]

Comment: Does this query produce any results when you run it manually?

Comment: If i use SELECT * FROM test.database i am getting the result but when i use time interval i am not getting any result. How to retrieve the last 5 min data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,from_unixtime(EndTime / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') FROM test.database WHERE EndTime >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) * 1000
```

You Need to change query.

Comment: By using your query i am getting all the records from the database instead of getting last 5 minutes data

Comment: Okay, How you insert timestamp values ? is it using mysql insert or your program ?

Comment: through api i am getting the json response in that response i had a string value EndTime(1519742280007). I am converting that string value to date using                                                                          
 long timestamp = Long.valueOf("1519742280007");

  Date d = new Date(timestamp);

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
  
  String EndTime= dateFormat.format(d);
And inserting the data using Java program as                                            pstmt.setTimestamp(2, java.sql.Timestamp.valueOf(EndTime));

Comment: Okay, As per the your first comments, you will get all the records. so can you see the "from_unixtime(EndTime / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')" output ? is it bellow 5 min ?. I think there is issue in the logic.

Comment: I didn't get the 5 minutes results, still i'm getting all the records. Please help me out

Comment: run the query again & see the output of the "from_unixtime(EndTime / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')" output, then check the that output values less than 5 min or not.  :)

Comment: still i am getting the same result (all records)